# Upload images to different folders on frontend using react, express and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, file-upload

I am trying to display different buttons on the frontend, with a "year" text on each of them, so if the user clicks on a button that says "2023". The user will get into this site and see all the images that someone has uploaded in the ./2023 site. The user can also upload his own images to this site. The same goes for, if the user clicks on a button that says "2022", he will then be displayed by the images that was uploaded on the ./2022 site.

I have managed to get the images to upload to the site, but they all appear on every site the user clicks into (no matter if it's ./2022, ./2023 etc.). I believe that creating a column in the database that shows a list of years, I can retrieve the images by filtering through the years, but I am not sure how to post the years to the database.

Can someone help?
This is my code. I am using useParams() to get the id (which will be the year) from the url.

Frontend

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { ImageGroup, Image } from "react-fullscreen-image";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export function MediaDetails() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3001/media/", {
        params: {
          id: id,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setFiles(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  const setimgfile = (event) => {
    setFiles(event.target.files);
  };

  const addUserData = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();

    for (const file of files) {
      formData.append("files", file);
    }

    axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/media/`, formData);
  };

  const fileList = files ? [...files] : [];

  const deleteFile = (fileId) => {
    const newFiles = [...files];
    const index = files.findIndex((file) => file.id === fileId);

    newFiles.splice(index, 1);
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/media/delete/${fileId}`);
    setFiles(newFiles);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ padding: 15, backgroundColor: "#fff", marginTop: 15 }}>
        <h4>Upload file:</h4>
        <input type="file" name="photo" onChange={setimgfile} multiple />
        <button type="submit" onClick={addUserData}>
          submit
        </button>
      </div>
      <ImageGroup>
        <ul
          className="images"
          style={{
            display: "grid",
            gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr))",
            gridGap: "15px",
            listStyleType: "none",
            margin: 0,
            padding: 0,
          }}
        >
          {fileList.map((file, i) => (
            <li key={i} style={{ position: "relative", paddingTop: "66%" }}>
              <button onClick={() => deleteFile(file.id)}>Slett</button>
              <Image
                key={file.id}
                src={"http://localhost:3001/images/" + file.image}
                alt={file.name}
                style={{
                  top: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  height: "auto",
                  width: "50%",
                }}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </ImageGroup>
    </>
  );
}
export default MediaDetails;
```

Backend

```
app.get("/media", (req, res) => {
  const sqlMedia = "SELECT * FROM media";
  db.query(sqlMedia, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json(err);
    } else {
      return res.json(result);
    }
  });
});

app.post("/media", upload, (req, res) => {
  const image = req.files;

  for (let img of image) {
    const sqlImage = "INSERT INTO media (image) VALUES (?);";
    db.query(sqlImage, [img.filename], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({ message: "Error uploading image" });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

So, in conclusion. Is there a way to store the id from useParams (which is the year) to the media table in the database, when the user uploads an image on that specific site?
Or is there another way to retrieve what I am after?